# Solve ODE using Fourier series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> I have that
>
> $$f(x)=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^n(1+i\pi
>  n)}{n^2}e^{i\pi n x}, \quad n\neq0\tag1$$
>
> and I want to find a 2-periodic function $y(x)$ that solves the
>   following diff-equation
>
> $$2y''-y'-y=f(x).\tag{2}$$

Since $(1)$ is a linear ODE I know that it's solution is of the form $y(x)=y_h+y_p.$ Finding $y_h$ is trivial and done by solving the characteristic equation. I found it to be $y_h=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x/2}.$

For $y_p$, I need to use $f(x)$ somehow, I could not find any good example in the book on how to do this. I only found [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzXnww4om80) video on youtube but it does not really seem to be that similar to my problem.

I want to follow the answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084455/calculate-a-n-and-b-n-for-a-complex-fourier-series/3084478#3084478) thread but I can't seem to grasp the mechanics of what he means. Can someone show me how to go about this?

Comment: Write the solution in its series form and plug it into the ODE to obtain a system of algebraic equations in terms of the Fourier coefficients. You already have $f$ in series form so this should be fairly straightforward

Comment: @Dylan - How do I write the solution in series form if I don't know the solution yet?

Comment: You write it as an unknown series, and derive the coefficients from the resulting equations. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $2$-periodic function has the form

$$ y(x) = c_0 + \sum_{n=\pm 1}^{\pm\infty} c_n e^{in\pi x} $$

where $c_n$ are unknown coefficients. Plug this expression into the ODE (differentiating term-wise)

$$ 2y'' - y' - y = - c_0 - \sum_{n=\pm1}^{\pm\infty} (n^2\pi^2 + in\pi + 1)c_n e^{in\pi x} $$

Comparing coefficients gives

\begin{align}
-c_0 &= \frac43 \\
-(n^2\pi^2+in\pi+1)c_n &= \frac{2}{\pi^2}(-1)^n \frac{1+in\pi}{n^2} 
\end{align}

The homogeneous solution is not periodic so it isn't needed.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I have a question, what is meant by "2-periodic"? and how does one see that the substitution for $y(x)$ is 2-periodic?

Comment: $2$-periodic means it has a period of $2$, i.e. $y(x+2)=y(x)$. How did you obtain the Fourier series of $f(x)$ in your earlier question? How did you know it has terms in $e^{in\pi x}$? How did you get through that question without knowing what it means?

Comment: Okay, maybe my question was a bit misleading. I know what periodicity refers to, however in my book it says that one can express a function $f$ on the form $$f(x)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_n e^{i n x},$$ so I'm wondering why you substituted $$y(x)=c_0+\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{in\pi x}.$$ Why do you latch on the $c_0$ when they excluded it in my book?

Comment: The first series does include a constant term. What is $e^{inx}$ when $n=0$?

Comment: Ok I got it now! Thanks.